# Query en arbol con cuentas por nivel

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

Buenas tardes, tengo una `tabla` que tiene `clave`, `clave_padre`, `anio` y `nivel`, y por otro lado tengo una `tabla2` que tiene la `clave`, `cargo`, `abono`, `mes` y `anio`.

Lo que trato es unir ambas tablas delimitadas por `anio`, `mes` y `nivel`, he tratado de usar `group by rollup` sin éxito porque el grupo de cuentas de la `tabla2` son solo del último nivel mientras que el catálogo completo se encuentra en `tabla`.

Un ejemplo de lo que espero es lo siguiente:

Tabla

```
  Clave     Clave_Padre     Nivel     Anio
  ----------------------------------------
  123       -1              1         2015
  123.1     123             2         2015
  123.1.1   123.1           3         2015
  123.1.2   123.1           3         2015
  123.1.3   123.1           3         2015
```

Tabla2

```
  Clave     Cargo     Abono     Mes
  ---------------------------------
  123.1.1   $50       $50       1
  123.1.1   $0        $50       2
  123.1.1   $0        $50       3
  123.1.1   $0        $50       7
  123.1.1   $0        $50       12
  123.1.2   $10       $0        2
  123.1.2   $10       $0        5
```

Y lo que quiero es agruparlos del siguiente modo:

Resultado: 2015

```
  Clave    Nivel     Mes     SUM(Cargo)     SUM(Abono)
  ----------------------------------------------------
  123      2         1       $50            $50
  123      2         2       $10            $50
  123      2         3       $0             $50
  123      2         5       $10            $0
  123      2         7       $0             $50
  123      2         12      $0             $50
  123.1    2         1       $50            $50
  123.1    2         2       $10            $50
  123.1    2         3       $0             $50
  123.1    2         5       $10            $0
  123.1    2         7       $0             $50
  123.1    2         12      $0             $50
  123.1.1  3         1       $50            $50
  123.1.1  3         2       $0             $50
  123.1.1  3         3       $0             $50
  123.1.1  3         7       $0             $50
  123.1.1  3         12      $0             $50
  123.1.2  3         2       $10            $0
  123.1.3  3         5       $10            $0
```

He tratado de usar rollup sin exito los join y tampoco he obtenido lo que necesito, alguna sugerencia?

### Edición de @Patricio Moracho al 21/6

Para que se entienda mejor la pregunta, agrego la siguiente explicación: En la contabilidad el plan de cuentas se arma con una estructura de tipo árbol, según la pregunta sería algo así:

```
Cuenta 123       
   Cuenta 123.1
      Cuenta 123.1.1
      Cuenta 123.1.2 
      Cuenta 123.1.3
```

Normalmente cuando se se ingresa un monto (debe/haber) en un asiento se lo imputa a la cuenta de menor nivel, en el ejemplo 123.1.1 a 123.1.3, pero ese monto se suma hacia arriba, es decir que 50$ a la 123.1.1 se suman además a las 123.1 y a la 123. La idea es poder ver la contabilidad con distintos niveles de detalle, un ejemplo real podría ser algo así:

```
Activo
  Caja Bancos
    Bancos Locales
      Santander
      ICBC
    Bancos del exterior
      UBS
      Morgan
```

Si imputamos un ingreso o egreso de $50 al ICBC lo que se esperaría ver es lo siguiente:

```
Activo                         50$
  Caja Bancos                  50$
    Bancos Locales             50$
      Santander
      ICBC                     50$
    Bancos del exterior
      UBS
      Morgan
```

y si luego imputamos 100$ al Morgan terminaríamos esperando esto:

```
Activo                        150$
  Caja Bancos                 150$
    Bancos Locales             50$ 
      Santander
      ICBC                     50$ 
    Bancos del exterior       100$
      UBS
      Morgan                  100$
```

Una forma de solucionarlo, lo cuento por que así lo suelo manejar, es sumarizar hacia arriba mediante un trigger  de update/insert en un tabla de acumuladores de cuenta por período. Lo que en realidad pide la pregunta es hacerlo distinto y que el acumulado hacia arriba se resuelva al momento de listar los datos.

Comment: No entiendo la lógica que te permite obtener el resultado a partir de tus 2 tablas. Tienes que explicarlo.

Comment: Si lo haces a nivel de query de base de datos, te resultará casi imposible en un solo query, deberías usar un procedimiento almacenado que pre procese la información y luego generar la respuesta. Lo mejor es controlar estas cosas a nivel de aplicación.

Comment: No es necesario el procedimiento almacenado, Oracle y muchos otros motores de datos permiten el tratamiento recursivo de la información en querys.

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente es una prueba de concepto sobre como podríamos implementar una solución al problema. La planteo en **TSQL** por que lamentablemente no tengo ahora un **Oracle** a mano para probarla, de todas formas salvo el uso de variables tipo Tabla que pueden ser remplazadas por tablas temporales comunes el resto es código bastante compatible.

La prueba esta planteado de una forma muy sencilla, tenemos un conjunto de cuentas, cada una con una cuenta padre y un conjunto de asientos que imputan un monto a alguna cuenta, lo que se busca es que dicho monto además de sumar en la cuenta a la que impute, lo haga hacia arriba, es decir sumando a su padre y al padre de este y así hasta llegar a las cuentas iniciales. No me preocupo en tener varios montos o manejar períodos simplemente para hacer más entendible la solución, no es complicado agregar luego estos datos.

Conceptualmente lo que vamos a hacer es generar una tabla intermedia dónde insertaremos cada cuenta y todas sus hijas, nietas y etc. hasta el final. Por ejemplo si partimos de esta tabla:

```
Cuenta  Padre
------  --------
123     NULL
123.1   123
123.1.1 123.1
123.1.2 123.1
123.1.3 123.1
123.2   123
123.2.1 123.2
```

La idea es generar esto:

```
Cuenta  CuentaHijo
------  ----------
123     123.1
123     123.2
123     123.1.1
123     123.1.2
123     123.1.3
123     123.2.1
123.1   123.1.1
123.1   123.1.2
123.1   123.1.3
123.2   123.2.1
123.1.1 123.1.1
123.1.2 123.1.2
123.1.3 123.1.3
123.2.1 123.2.1
```

Teniendo esta estructura y desde un tabla donde tendremos los importes a imputar (en mi ejemplo `@Asientos`) simplemente haciendo un `LEFT JOIN` podremos saber que un monto imputado a la cuenta `123.1.3` debe sumar a la propia `123.2.3` a la `123.1` y a la `123`

Este es el código:

```
DECLARE @Cuentas  TABLE(
  Cuenta        VARCHAR(15),
  CuentaPadre   VARCHAR(15)
)

DECLARE @Asientos  TABLE(
    Cuenta  VARCHAR(15),
    Monto   NUMERIC(15,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Cuentas(Cuenta, CuentaPadre)
SELECT '123',       NULL    UNION
SELECT '123.1',     '123'   UNION
SELECT '123.1.1',   '123.1' UNION
SELECT '123.1.2',   '123.1' UNION
SELECT '123.1.3',   '123.1' UNION
SELECT '123.2',     '123'   UNION
SELECT '123.2.1',   '123.2'

INSERT INTO @Asientos (Cuenta, Monto)
SELECT '123.1.1', 10    UNION
SELECT '123.1.3', 20    UNION
SELECT '123.2.1', 40    

DECLARE @CuentasFinal  TABLE(
  Cuenta    VARCHAR(15),
  CuentaHijo    VARCHAR(15)
)

DECLARE @Rows           INT

-- Inserto todas las cuentas
INSERT INTO @CuentasFinal (Cuenta, CuentaHijo)
SELECT  CuentaPadre, Cuenta
    FROM    @Cuentas
    WHERE CuentaPadre IS NOT NULL

SELECT  @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE   @Rows <> 0
BEGIN

    -- inserto todos los hijos posibles de cualquier cuenta
    INSERT INTO @CuentasFinal (Cuenta, CuentaHijo)
    SELECT  CF2.Cuenta, CF.CuentaHijo
        FROM    @CuentasFinal CF
        INNER JOIN @CuentasFinal CF2
            ON CF.Cuenta = CF2.CuentaHijo
        LEFT JOIN @CuentasFinal CF3
            ON CF3.Cuenta = CF2.Cuenta
            AND CF3.CuentaHijo = CF.CuentaHijo
        WHERE CF3.Cuenta IS NULL

    SELECT  @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

END

-- Inserto las ramas finales del arbol de cuenta
INSERT INTO @CuentasFinal (Cuenta, CuentaHijo)
SELECT  CF.CuentaHijo, CF.CuentaHijo
    FROM    @CuentasFinal CF
    LEFT JOIN @CuentasFinal CF2
        ON CF2.Cuenta = CF.CuentaHijo
    WHERE CF2.Cuenta IS NULL
    GROUP BY CF.CuentaHijo, CF.CuentaHijo


SELECT  C.Cuenta,
    SUM(ISNULL(A.Monto,0)) 
    FROM @Cuentas C
    LEFT JOIN @CuentasFinal CF
        ON C.Cuenta = CF.Cuenta
    LEFT JOIN @Asientos A
        ON A.Cuenta = CF.CuentaHijo
    GROUP BY C.Cuenta
    ORDER BY C.Cuenta
```

La tabla de los Asientos sería:

```
Cuenta  Monto
------- -----
123.1.1 10,00
123.1.3 20,00
123.2.1 40,00
```

y el resultado final:

```
Cuenta  Monto
------- -----  
123     70,00
123.1   30,00
123.1.1 10,00
123.1.2 0,00
123.1.3 20,00
123.2   40,00
123.2.1 40,00
```

Dependiendo de el plan de cuentas y la cantidad de niveles, generar nuestra tabla intermedia `@CuentasFinal` puede ser bastante costoso para hacerlo bajo demanda, por lo que la otra alternativa que ya comenté en la edición de la pregunta, es mantener una tabla de acumuladores por cuenta y período y al insertar un nuevo monto actualizar automáticamente toda la rama hacía arriba, esto agregaría un costo a los INSERT's pero nos dejaría la información lista como para consultarla.

**algunas ideas posteriores**

- Para optimizar un poco la generación de nuestra tabla de atribuciones `@CuentasFinal` se podría procesar solo las cuentas qué tienen movimientos.
- Mucho mejor es mantener `@CuentasFinal` como una tabla fija que habría que actualizar cuan haya cambios en el maestro de cuentas

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el problema en un solo query ha de plantearse un query recursivo. Este tipo de query esta definido en el estandar SQL-99 implementado al día de hoy por la mayoría de los motores de base de datos. Oracle maneja una forma alternativa de construir el query sin embargo te presento una forma estandar que funciona perfectamente sobre Oracle 12c y muy seguramente sobre Oracle 11g (aunque sobre la version 11g no puedo probarlo en este momento).

```
create table TABALANCETEST(

     CLAVE VARCHAR2( 10),
     CLAVE_PADRE VARCHAR2( 10),
     NIVEL NUMBER(2),
     ANIO NUMBER

);

INSERT INTO TABALANCETEST( CLAVE, CLAVE_PADRE, NIVEL, ANIO) VALUES ( '123', '-1', 1, 2015 );
INSERT INTO TABALANCETEST( CLAVE, CLAVE_PADRE, NIVEL, ANIO) VALUES ( '123.1', '123', 2, 2015 );
INSERT INTO TABALANCETEST( CLAVE, CLAVE_PADRE, NIVEL, ANIO) VALUES ( '123.1.1', '123.1', 3, 2015 );
INSERT INTO TABALANCETEST( CLAVE, CLAVE_PADRE, NIVEL, ANIO) VALUES ( '123.1.2', '123.1', 3, 2015 );
INSERT INTO TABALANCETEST( CLAVE, CLAVE_PADRE, NIVEL, ANIO) VALUES ( '123.1.3', '123.1', 3, 2015 );


CREATE TABLE TAIMPORTES (
     CLAVE VARCHAR2( 10),
     CARGO NUMBER(10, 2),
     ABONO NUMBER(10, 2),
     MES NUMBER(2)

);


INSERT INTO TAIMPORTES ( CLAVE, CARGO, ABONO, MES) VALUES ( '123.1.1', 50, 50, 1);
INSERT INTO TAIMPORTES ( CLAVE, CARGO, ABONO, MES) VALUES ( '123.1.1', 0, 50, 2);
INSERT INTO TAIMPORTES ( CLAVE, CARGO, ABONO, MES) VALUES ( '123.1.1', 0, 50, 3);
INSERT INTO TAIMPORTES ( CLAVE, CARGO, ABONO, MES) VALUES ( '123.1.1', 0, 50, 7);
INSERT INTO TAIMPORTES ( CLAVE, CARGO, ABONO, MES) VALUES ( '123.1.1', 0, 50, 12);
INSERT INTO TAIMPORTES ( CLAVE, CARGO, ABONO, MES) VALUES ( '123.1.1', 10, 0, 2);
INSERT INTO TAIMPORTES ( CLAVE, CARGO, ABONO, MES) VALUES ( '123.1.1', 10, 0, 5);



     WITH TTTODO AS (
      SELECT cuentas.CLAVE
           , cuentas.CLAVE_PADRE
           , cuentas.NIVEL
           , importes.MES
           , importes.CARGO
           , importes.ABONO
         FROM TABALANCETEST cuentas
    LEFT JOIN TAIMPORTES importes
           ON cuentas.CLAVE = importes.CLAVE

       -- el siguiente bloque define los campos que saldran de la recursion.    
    ), TTRECURSIVO( CLAVE, CLAVE_PADRE, NIVEL, MES, CARGO, ABONO ) AS (
       -- este es el caso base de la recursion.
      SELECT CLAVE
           , CLAVE_PADRE
           , NIVEL
           , MES
           , CARGO
           , ABONO         
        FROM TTTODO
       WHERE CARGO IS NOT NULL
         AND ABONO IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
       -- este es el caso recursivo de la recursion
       SELECT actual.CLAVE
           , actual.CLAVE_PADRE
           , actual.NIVEL
           , anterior.MES
           , anterior.CARGO
           , anterior.ABONO
         FROM TTTODO actual
         JOIN TTRECURSIVO anterior
           ON anterior.CLAVE_PADRE  = actual.CLAVE     
    )
      SELECT CLAVE
           , NIVEL
           , MES
           , SUM( CARGO ) CARGO
           , SUM( ABONO ) ABONO
        FROM TTRECURSIVO
    GROUP BY CLAVE
           , NIVEL
           , MES
    ORDER BY CLAVE 
           , NIVEL
           , MES
```

Lo que nos arroja la salida:

[image: Salida como lo soliciado]
Espero que aun te sirva. 
Como nota extra debo decir que los sistemas contables como SAP realizan un proceso equivalente al ahora expuesto.