# SQL Server Ordenar una tabla recursiva

Tags: sql-server, tablas

Tengo la siguiente tabla recursiva (padres e hijos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer una consulta que me devuelva el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán, quiero que se desglosen todos los hijos de un padre (por ejemplo, ACTIVO NO CORRIENTE) para que se desglosen todos los hijos del siguiente padre (ACTIVO CORRIENTE). Si tienen alguna duda sobre mi consulta me la dicen.

Aquí les dejo el script de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE secDefinicionBalance(
  BalanceID int NOT NULL,
  Codigo varchar(8) NULL,
  Nivel int NULL,
  Descripcion varchar(100) NULL,
  Signo int NULL,
  PadreID int NULL,
  Arbol char(1) NULL
) 

INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (1, N'A', 1, N'ACTIVO', 0, 0, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (2, N'A', 2, N'ACTIVO NO CORRIENTE', 0, 1, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (3, N'B', 2, N'ACTIVO CORRIENTE', 0, 1, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (4, N'I', 3, N'Inmovilizado Intangible', 0, 2, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (5, N'II', 3, N'Inmovilizado material', 0, 2, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (6, N'III', 3, N'Inversiones inmobiliarias', 0, 2, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (7, N'IV', 3, N'Inversiones en empresas del grupo y asociadas a largo plazo', 0, 2, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (8, N'V', 3, N'Inversiones financieras a largo plazo', 0, 2, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (9, N'VI', 3, N'Activos por impuesto diferido', 0, 2, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (10, N'I', 3, N'Activos no corrientes mantenidos para la venta', 0, 3, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (11, N'II', 3, N'Existencias', 0, 3, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (12, N'III', 3, N'Deudores comerciales y otras cuentas a cobrar', 0, 3, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (13, N'IV', 3, N'Inversiones en empresas del grupo y asociadas a corto plazo', 0, 3, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (14, N'V', 3, N'Inversiones financieras a corto plazo', 0, 3, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (15, N'VI', 3, N'Periodificaciones a corto plazo', 0, 3, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (16, N'VII', 3, N'Efectivo y otros activos líquidos equivalentes', 0, 3, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (17, N'1', 4, N'Desarrollo', 0, 4, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (18, N'2', 4, N'Concesiones', 0, 4, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (19, N'3', 4, N'Patentes, licencias, marcas y similares', 0, 4, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (20, N'4', 4, N'Fondo de comercio', 0, 4, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (21, N'5', 4, N'Aplicaciones informáticas', 0, 4, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (22, N'6', 4, N'Otro inmovilizado intangible', 0, 4, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (23, N'1', 4, N'Terrenos y construcciones', 0, 5, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (24, N'2', 4, N'Instalaciones técnicas y otro inmovilizado material', 0, 5, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (25, N'3', 4, N'Inmovilizado en curso y anticipos', 0, 5, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (26, N'1', 4, N'Terrenos', 0, 6, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (27, N'2', 4, N'Construcciones', 0, 6, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (28, N'1', 4, N'Instrumentos de patrimonio', 0, 7, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (29, N'2', 4, N'Créditos a empresas', 0, 7, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (30, N'3', 4, N'Valores representativos de deuda', 0, 7, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (72, N'201', 5, N'Cuenta 201', 1, 17, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (73, N'2801', 5, N'Cuenta 2801', 1, 17, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (74, N'2901', 5, N'Cuenta 2901', 1, 17, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (75, N'202', 5, N'Cuenta 202', 1, 18, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (76, N'2802', 5, N'Cuenta 2802', 1, 18, N'A')
INSERT secDefinicionBalance (BalanceID, Codigo, Nivel, Descripcion, Signo, PadreID, Arbol) VALUES (77, N'2902', 5, N'Cuenta 2902 abc', 1, 18, N'A')
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Query en arbol con cuentas por nivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78384/query-en-arbol-con-cuentas-por-nivel)

Comment: Podrías poner tus datos como INSERTs o al menos como texto? Las imágenes no las puedo usar para pruebas.

Comment: @LuisCazares ya publique el script para que puedas hacer tus pruebas, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método más confiable que he encontrado para esto, es ir concatenando los valores en un varbinary para generar una ruta confiable. Dejo la opción de hacerlo y además una ruta que sirve para hacerlo más amigable al ojo humano.

```
WITH cteDefinicionBalance AS (
    SELECT  BalanceID,  
            Codigo, 
            Nivel,  
            Descripcion,    
            Signo,  
            PadreID,    
            Arbol,
            Ruta =  CAST( Nivel AS varchar(8000)), --Ruta legible para humanos
            RutaJerarquica = CAST(BalanceID AS VARBINARY(max)) --Ruta confiable para orden.
    FROM dbo.secDefinicionBalance
    WHERE Nivel = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  db.BalanceID,   
            db.Codigo,  
            db.Nivel,   
            db.Descripcion, 
            db.Signo,   
            db.PadreID, 
            db.Arbol,
            Ruta = c.Ruta + '.' + CAST( db.Nivel AS varchar(10)),
            RutaJerarquica = c.RutaJerarquica +  CAST( db.BalanceID AS varbinary(max))
    FROM       dbo.secDefinicionBalance db
    INNER JOIN cteDefinicionBalance     c  ON db.PadreID = c.BalanceID
)
 SELECT *
   FROM cteDefinicionBalance
  ORDER BY RutaJerarquica;
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un CTE recursivo puedes conseguirlo, aunque deberás probar la ordenación que más te convenga.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT BalanceID, PadreID, Nivel, Descripcion, CAST(BalanceID AS varbinary(max)) AS Orden
    FROM secDefinicionBalance
    WHERE PadreID = 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.BalanceID, t.PadreID, t.Nivel, t.Descripcion, Orden + CAST(t.PadreID AS varbinary(max)) AS Orden
    FROM secDefinicionBalance t
    INNER JOIN CTE c ON t.PadreID = c.BalanceID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY Orden;
```

Comment: El orden es un de los puntos importantes de mi problema. La solución que envías no devuelve el orden que necesito.

Comment: He cambiado el código para añadir una ordenación según la jerarquía